# What is the easiest way to automatically log mathematical expression?

Tags: c#, .net

Often I need to perform some mathematical operations in the code. E.g.

```
var par1 = 100;
var par2 = 200;
var par3 = 300;

var result = (par1 + par2) / par3;
```

I also want to save the calculation steps for logging purposes.

```
    var loggingMessage = string.Format(
      "result = (par1 + par2) / par3; [{0} = ({1} + {2}) / {3}]",
      result,
      par1,
      par2,
      par3
    );
```

As I do it quite regularly it drives me crazy to do this monkey job. Also it is very difficult to maintain.

I know it could be done with for example reverse polish notation but I don't want to generate such a huge overkill for these simple mathematical actions.

Are there any smart solutions for this issue?

Comment: Use a debugger.  This kind of logging is too trite to be useful.  Only log the unpredictable and error-prone stuff, division is not unpredictable.

Comment: ok, it is not going about division, it is about certain financial rules which need to applied. Based on certain criteria 1,2 or 10 different formulas can be used to get the final calculation. I believe it is useful to have it displayed to the user.

Comment: Interpolated string should be a good compromise to log some intermediate values (because it's easy to read and maintain): `Logger.Add($"Result: {result} = ({par1} + {par2}) / {par3}");`. You don't need to log complete formulas every time. Only calculated result and operands (to be able to see if one of them is invalid, e.g. `NaN` or unexpected). User log is totally different task, if user require, then you have to stop using `C#` operands and create own class via each all operations are done, e.g. `MyMath.Add()` or simply own type (`MyDouble`) where you override all operators to do logging.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's not much that can be done to simplify this, but you could start using expression trees:

```
    var par1 = 100;
    var par2 = 200;
    var par3 = 300;

    Expression<Func<int, int, int, int>> expr = (a, b, c) => (a + b) / c;
    Func<int, int, int, int> func = expr.Compile();

    int result = func(par1, par2, par3);
    string exprAsText = expr.ToString();
    string exprWithValues = exprAsText.Replace("result", result.ToString())
                                      .Replace("a", par1.ToString())
                                      .Replace("b", par2.ToString())
                                      .Replace("c", par3.ToString());

    string logMessage = $"result = {exprAsText} ({result} = {exprWithValues})";
    Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
```

Since you're storing your ops as expression trees, you could easily work in some abstraction/generalization to print out these log messages.

Maybe you find the following code an overkill, but it does the job right:

```
// Define your mathematical operations in a static class, and use them
// across your solution
public static class MathOps
{
    public static Expression<Func<int, int, int, int>> SumAndDivide { get; } = (a, b, c) => (a + b) / c;
}

public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static object ExecuteAndLog<TExpr>(this TExpr expr, object args)
        where TExpr : LambdaExpression
    {
        Contract.Requires(expr != null);
        Contract.Requires(args != null);

        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> argsProperties =
            args.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

        Contract.Assert(expr.Parameters.Count == argsProperties.Count());

        Delegate compiledDelegate = expr.Compile();

        string exprAsText = expr.Body.ToString();
        string replacedExprAsText = (string)exprAsText.Clone();
        List<object> delegateArgs = new List<object>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in argsProperties)
        {
            delegateArgs.Add(property.GetValue(args));
            replacedExprAsText = replacedExprAsText.Replace(property.Name, property.GetValue(args)?.ToString());
        }

        object result = compiledDelegate.DynamicInvoke(delegateArgs.ToArray());
        string logMessage = $"result = {exprAsText} ({result} = {replacedExprAsText})";

        // Replace this with your logger
        Trace.WriteLine(logMessage);

        return result;
    }
}
```

...and you can use it this way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // You give operation arguments as an object. An anonymous
        // object can be enough!
        int result = (int)MathOps.SumAndDivide.ExecuteAndLog
        (
            new
            {
                a = 100,
                b = 200,
                c = 300
            }
        );

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Now it's your turn to refactor it. Probably, in a final solution, I would separate the math operations and logging into different concerns, but since this is just an answer, I've tried to be as compact as possible with my proposed code ;)

### Working sample...

...here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XloiSC

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class `myMaths` that contains the operations you need.

```
public class myMaths
{

    private string _LoggedOperations = "";

    public myMaths()
    {
        _LoggedOperations = "";
    }

    //(A + B) / C
    public double BR_A_plus_B_BR_dev_C(double A, double B, double C)
    {
        double result = (A + B) / C;
        if (_LoggedOperations != "") _LoggedOperations += "\n";
        _LoggedOperations += string.Format("result = (A + B) / C; [{0} = ({1} + {2}) / {3}]", result, A, B, C);
        return result;
    }

    //(A - B) / C
    public double BR_A_minus_B_BR_dev_C(double A, double B, double C)
    {
        double result = (A - B) / C;
        if (_LoggedOperations != "") _LoggedOperations += "\n";
        _LoggedOperations += string.Format("result = (A - B) / C; [{0} = ({1} - {2}) / {3}]", result, A, B, C);
        return result;
    }

    //(A - B) * C
    public double BR_A_minus_B_BR_times_C(double A, double B, double C)
    {
        double result = (A - B) * C;
        if (_LoggedOperations != "") _LoggedOperations += "\n";
        _LoggedOperations += string.Format("result = (A - B) * C; [{0} = ({1} - {2}) * {3}]", result, A, B, C);
        return result;
    }

    //((A + B) * C) / D
    public double BR_BR_A_plus_B_BR_times_C_BR_dev_D(double A, double B, double C, double D)
    {
        double result = ((A + B) * C) / D;
        if (_LoggedOperations != "") _LoggedOperations += "\n";
        _LoggedOperations += string.Format("result = ((A + B) * C) / D; [{0} = (({1} + {2}) * {3}) / {4}]", result, A, B, C, D);
        return result;
    }

    public string LoggedOperations
    {
        get { return _LoggedOperations; }
    }

}
```

And use it like this:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myMaths m = new myMaths();
        var par1 = 100;
        var par2 = 200;
        var par3 = 300;
        var par4 = 5;
        double result1 = m.BR_A_plus_B_BR_dev_C(par1, par2, par3);
        double result2 = m.BR_A_minus_B_BR_dev_C(par1, par2, par3);
        double result3 = m.BR_A_minus_B_BR_times_C(par1, par2, par3);
        double result4 = m.BR_BR_A_plus_B_BR_times_C_BR_dev_D(par1, par2, par3, par4);

        MessageBox.Show(m.LoggedOperations);
    }
```